# weblogic with elipselink java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: rest, eclipselink, weblogic12c, vs-web-application-project

I am deploying my rest service war to weblogic 12.1.3.
I have set true as my rest war is first to find by class loader.

I have also set app package preferences as below  :

```
 <prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>javax.xml.ws.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.xml.ws</package-name>
<package-name>javax.xml.bind.*</package-name>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117584/server-sent-event-with-jersey-and-weblogic
<package-name>javax.jws.*</package-name>
<package-name>javax.xml.soap.*</package-name>
<package-name>javax.servlet.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

But getting this execption below :

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:226)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:418)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:210)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:118)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1017)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:388)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:430)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused By: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethodInfo(Class.java:964)
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Class.java:1137)
    at java.lang.Class.getCanonicalName(Class.java:1231)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.javamodel.reflection.JavaModelImpl.getClass(JavaModelImpl.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.javamodel.reflection.JavaClassImpl.getSuperclass(JavaClassImpl.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.javamodel.reflection.JavaClassImpl.hasCustomSuperClass(JavaClassImpl.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.javamodel.reflection.JavaClassImpl.isAssignableFrom(JavaClassImpl.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.javamodel.Helper.isCollectionType(Helper.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.shouldGenerateTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:1821)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processClass(AnnotationsProcessor.java:1304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processAdditionalClasses(AnnotationsProcessor.java:1291)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processAdditionalClasses(AnnotationsProcessor.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:747)
```

Also share valuable points on how to deploy my jax RS+ spring rest based war on weblogic by avoiding all internal weblogic jars with web app first class loading strategy.

Comment: Apparently your application has a model that requires more stack space then you have allocated in order to allow it to be processed recursively for deployment.  Try increasing the Xss allocations on your server, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158606/how-to-increase-memory-in-weblogic

Comment: -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xss10m didi not solve the problem

Comment: i solved this problem by turning off the annotation scanning of weblogic server Setting java option to server start up script .-Dweblogic.servlet.DIDisabled=true

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by turning off the annotation scanning of weblogic server Setting java option to server start up script .-Dweblogic.servlet.DIDisabled=true